# call webservice from content page from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to call a autocomplete webservice from javascript from a content page.webservice is in the same web app itself.if i use a simple .aspx page it calls the webservice and everything works fine.but as soon as i apply master page to it,it doesnt work at all.i have not placed script manager on master page.so i want to use script manager on content page itself.
i have googled for it and applied the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     SearchText();
 });
 function SearchText() {
     $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 url: "AutoComplete.asmx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                 data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                     response(data.d);
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert("Error");
                 }
             });
         }
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Open up your browser's console and run `$("#txtSearch")` on your page do you get a result or an empty array?

Comment: As soon as you use     ScriptManager  try to use pagemethods.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *RegisterClientScriptBlock* to register your script in Page_Load event.